# How to count specific folders under UNIX

Tags: unix

i would like to ask you, if there is any way to count specific folders in my directory. it looks like this:

mydir/
     2004..2013/
         jan...dec/
            01.01.04...31.1.04/
                    10000                    .
                     .
                     .
                    20000 
                     .
                     .99999

so its like: year/month/day-in-month/serial nr. folder/

What I need is to count all folders with serial nrs but in two groups:
1. count all serial nrs starting with "1"
2. count all other serial numbers

I am not very familiar with UNIX, so i will appreciate if someone can help me.

Thx, in advance.

Comment: See `man find`, `man wc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `find . -mindepth 4 -type "d" -name "1*" | wc -l` from mydir; and then `find . -mindepth 4 -type "d" -name "[2-9]*" | wc -l`